# Initializing Instance Attributes with a For loop

Tags: python, oop, python-class

So I'm trying to write a python class which takes four arguments, checks if any of the parameter is `None`. If it is none, then `self.parameter = 'None'` else `self.parameter = parameter`.

I am writing the code snippet below.

```
class meta():
    def __init__(self, color, size, symbol, message):
        for a in [color, size, symbol, message]:
            if a == 'None':
                self.a = 'None'
            else:
                self.a = a
```

Now I know the error here, the `self.a` is being assigned as the instance variable. But I want the instance variables to loop through the values of a `self.color, self.size, self.symbol, self.message`.

How can I achieve the required functionality?

Comment: Not clear what is goal of your if condition?

Comment: I'm basically working upon a Flask App and this class takes the arguments from a URL. Those arguments come from an HTML form. So it is a case when does not selects an attribute in the form and it is returned as 'None' in the URL. So that's why I have to keep the check for the 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` is not necessary, because a is `'None'`.

So the function simplifies to

```
class meta():
    def __init__(self, color, size, symbol, message):
        for a in [color, size, symbol, message]:
            self.a = a
```

Next, you have to provide the name of the attributes explicitly:

```
class meta():
    def __init__(self, color, size, symbol, message):
        for name, value in [('color', color), ('size', size), ('symbol', symbol), ('message', message)]:
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

So you cannot simplify your code with a for-loop, it only gets more complicated than simply assigning attributes:

```
class meta():
    def __init__(self, color, size, symbol, message):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.message = message
```

Comment: What do you think about one more case is `kwargs` without `args`?

Comment: Alright, got the point, thanks for the explanation. The setattr() does the job. I think I might keep the if statement, because I am getting the arguments from a URL, so None is a string. Thanks for the help!